# acceptable ranges for PSNR values in image quality

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, image-compression

I am working on a bitrate assignment based on the changes in the RD curve. I need a reference that shows the range of PSNR values to find out which values are acceptable without changes in quality. for example, if I decrease PSNR from 40db to 35db the quality will not change a lot and our eyes can not detect the changes (jnd). could you please tell me is any reference that shows the acceptable ranges for PSNR values?

Comment: no one have any suggestions or references?

Comment: do you realize that you're asking about human perception? can you make this a programming problem? [help/on-topic]